# Wave row-level security with Account Teams

Tags: einstein-analytics

Wave honours some of the [Salesforce row-level data security mechanisms](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_security_datasets_row_level.htm&language=en_US), sometimes with a bit of tweaking. I am facing a situation wherein I need to create dashboards based on a custom object which has a Master-Detail relationship with the Account object, and data security within the Org is enforced using Account Teams.

It is not obvious how to restrict access to the child records based on account team membership. Has anyone had to deal with this before? We have attempted several different types of augmentation but none are appropriate for my situation.